# PRG (POST / Redirect / GET) model for forms and registration forms

Tags: forms, redirect, post, get, submit

I have known about the PRG approach for HTML forms, a model oriented to avoid re-submitting issues. I can understand the benefits when purchasing a product in an e-commerce. Even if you hit back button or hit F5 (Refresh), as you have been redirected to a GET page, you will always get the final page, in which you can say if the purchase has been correct, and you'll never get the original POST page, avoiding thus purchasing twice the same item (apart from additional server countermeasures to avoid this).

But I cannot grasp the concept for a registration form. In a form of this type, it is very frequent that you will miss some field or enter some incorrect data (for example, non matching password and password-repeat). As you must be shown (server-side) the message with all the possible errors, I would assume that you stay in the same POST page and that PRG would not apply in this case. Because if it would apply, in order to refill the original data entered by the user, you must use POST-Redirect-GET, with the final GET with all the original submitted data, and then, why not starting with a GET form from the very beginning? Am I correct or am I missing something?

Summarizing, PRG for one-click data (purchase of item), usual approach for Registration forms, Contact forms and the like?

Answer (score 0):

Use GET request for displaying data, and let the POST handling state-changing operations (change credentials, download a file etc.)

> GET method SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
> other than retrieval ([RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.1.1), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Safe_methods))

Let's explain it with a simple php example, you have three files:

- loginForm.php (with the registration form)
- loginAction.php (with the validation functions)
- welcome.php, that displays the welcome message if the registration is succesful

`loginForm.php`

```
<form method="post" action="loginAction.php">
     <input ...>
```

`loginAction.php`

```
<? if(dataValidate($_POST)){
       header('Location: welcome.php');
   }else{
       $_SESSION[error] = "Data not vaild";
       header('Location: loginForm.php');
   }
   die();
```

When loginAction.php receives the POST data, checks where to redirect the user. If there are errors, you can store a SESSION variable and display it in the loginForm.php.

---

Let's complicate a bit the things: lots of applications POST data to the same page, so loginForm.php and loginAction.php logic are in the same file.

In this case, you should redirect the user only in case of valid registration

> The PRG pattern definitely does not require you to perform a redirect for all POSTs, just for a POST that has changed the state of the data. (*[Source](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-post-redirect-get-pattern/)*).